# Flutter : How to change format dateTime with mounth in String?

Tags: flutter

hello I don't succeded to output this code in this format ( 04 Juin 2019 )

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
var daysfromnow = now.add(new Duration(days: changedate));

RegExp regExp = new RegExp(       
    r"(^\S*)",
);

var match = regExp.firstMatch("$daysfromnow");
daysfromnow_modify = match.group(1);
```

> current outpub : 2019-06-04
>
> expected output : 04 juin 2019

Update:

I tried to format but I don't succeded to change days when I press button...

here is the new code

```
     new IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left),

              onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          changedate--;
          DateTime now = DateTime.now();
          formattedDate = DateFormat.yMMMMd("en_FR").format(now);
          daysfromnow = formattedDate.add(new Duration(days: changedate));  //add can't be a String ...
});
)}
```

I tried this also ..

```
 formattedDate = DateFormat.yMMMMd("en_FR").now.add(new Duration(days: changedate));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use a DateFormat, just include [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) dependency to your pubspec.yaml

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat("dMMMMy")format(now);
print(formattedDate);
```

Depending on what your requirements is, you can look at [DateFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Some examples taken from DateFormat-class to help you a bit more.

```
String formattedDate = DateFormat.yMd(); // 7/10/1996
String formattedDate = DateFormat("yMd"); // 7/10/1996
String formattedDate = DateFormat.yMMMMd("en_US"); // July 10, 1996
String formattedDate = DateFormat.yMMMMd("en_FR"); // 10 July 1996 // Locale French
```

**UPDATE**

First add the value to the date and then call the format.

Example:

```
setState(() {
    changedate--;
    var now = DateTime.now(); // Current Date
    var daysFromNow = now.add(new Duration(days: changedate); // Assuming this is the date you want (Variable is unclear)

    String formattedDate = DateFormat.yMMMMd('en_FR').format(daysFromNow);
    print(formattedDate);

   // daysfromnow = formattedDate // This cannot exist due to the formattedDate is a `String`
});
```

Comment: thank you I tried, but now I can't use var daysfromnow = now.add(new Duration(days: changedate));  I use this code to increase or decrease days when I press button  I tried to add this but "add can't be a String          daysfromnow = formattedDate.add(new Duration(days: changedate));