# how do convert date formated in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an instance of Date(20201107) and I would like to format that to a String. How do I do that? I want to turn the date into a string, something like "07/11/2020".
And I have an instance of Time(103942) become to "10:39:42".

How to implement in widget? thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart)

Comment: I would suggest to use the `intl` package rather that `date_format:`

Comment: but Time Formatted how do?

Comment: @fluttdev You can find that in the linked question too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DateFormat, just include intl dependency to your pubspec.yaml

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")format(now);
print(formattedDate);
```

Depending on what your requirements is, you can look at DateFormat

Some examples taken from DateFormat-class to help you a bit more.

```
String formattedDate = DateFormat.yMd(); // 7/10/1996
String formattedDate = DateFormat("yMd"); // 7/10/1996
String formattedDate = DateFormat.yMMMMd("en_US"); // July 10, 1996
```

Also see [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56442469/4712391)

#### References

- [Intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)
- [DateFormat Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Comment: but the Time Formatted how do?

Comment: just use `DateFormat('dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss')` see [DateFormat class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Comment: how about variabel Time(103942) become to "10:39:42"